# regex, getting img without "noresize" tag in an html file

Tags: php, regex

I plan to work on each img of an html file. Those images must not contain the word "noresize".
I built the regex to get img :

```
#<img(\s[^>]*)>#ie
```

This is working quite well but I can't find how to specify "without noresize".

I tried something like that :

```
#<img(\s[^>]*)((?!noresize).)>#ie
```

But obviously, that's not what I need...

Any Idea ?
Julien

Comment: Thou shalt not parse HTML using regular expressions.

Comment: Thou shalt use a [DOM parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) to walk through the HTML, and cleanly extract the elements you want.

Comment: Seriously though, welcome to SO. Parsing HTML with regular expressions is kind of a running gag around here, thus the response. Still, using a DOM parser really is the best idea for this.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for the job. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Trying to use regexes to parse HTML is like using cheese to build a battleship. In the middle of a volcano. While it is erupting.

Comment: ... without a fondue pot, bread, or forks.

Answer (score 0):

This is using XPath, which I think would be a better solution to your problem ;)

```
//img[not(@resize*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already successfully capturing the IMG tags with your regex why not just run a little post-processing on each match like `stripos($tag, 'noresize') === false` - of course this would also incorrectly detect image names like `noresize.jpg`.

Or, just use and HTML/DOM parser like a normal human being:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
'/<img(((?!noresize)[^>])*)>/ie'
```